# ASP.net C# Populating Gridview columns from list

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to bind a list to specific columns, I can get it to autogenerate columns from the list but I want to specify a column to populate

```
        GridView1.DataSource = carlist;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: hi your code is a little sparse, which column are you trying to populate and where are you getting the data to populate from?

Comment: You mean you want one column populated? Just set that one up as a BoundColumn wih the DataField set to the field name and HeaderText to what you want he header to be, and set AutoGenerateColumns to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what type carlist contains, but assuming contains car objects that have a ModelName property:

```
  <asp:GridView  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ID="myGrid" runat="server">

   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Model Name" DataField="ModelName" />
```